# Twilio - subflow

Tags: twilio

Max of 20 Subflow widgets can be added to a parent Flow and those widgets can only reference up to 5 unique Subflow definitions.
I'm not understand what's "those widgets can only reference up to 5 unique Subflow definitions." means?
I have test connect to 6 unique subflow in a parent flow, it's works.

Answer (score 0):

Please contact Twilio Support either via the Twilio Console (upper right corner under the ?, submit a ticket) or help@twilio.com with your question above and your Twilio account SID. They should be able to engage the product manager for additional details on this pilot feature.

Comment: Okay. Thank you Alan!